# Como identificar acrônimos com RegEx JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Preciso identificar acrônimos que:

- Iniciem com `P`
- Possua 3 caracteres
- Os 2 últimos caracteres podem ser dígitos ou letras.

Atualmente, consegui fazer criar a regex `\b(?:[A-Za-z0-9]){3}` mas infelizmente não estou conseguindo a regra de "iniciar com P".

Alguns exemplos dos acrônimos seriam: `PCC`, `PC4`, `PCA`, `P00`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex que você está a procura é:

```
^P[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}$
```

Significado:

```
^ - Inicio da linha
P - A letra P maiúscula
[a-zA-Z0-9]{2} - Uma letra ou um digito duas vezes
$ - Fim da linha
```

Exemplo em JS:

```js
const entrada = ['PCC', 'ABC', '9C4', 'PC4', 'XYZ', 'PCA', 'P00'];
for (let acronimo of entrada){
  console.log(acronimo, /^P[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}$/.test(acronimo));
}
```

No exemplo usei o método `test` da regex diretamente dentro do `console.log`, mas se quiser testar isoladamente num if basta fazer assim:

```
if (/^P[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}$/.test(acronimoQueQuerTestar)){
    //acronimo valido
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Essa regex resolve seu problema: `/\bP[0-9A-Z]{2}\b/gi`

Explicando:

- `\b` é uma borda, importante para que resultados como `PCCC` não sejam retornados, veja que há uma letra a mais.
- `[0-9]` intervalo de 0 até 9, ou seja, números
- `[A-Z]` intervalo de A até Z.
- `{2}` quantificador que vai pegar apenas 2 letras.
- `g` flag que captura todos os resultados possíveis.
- `i` não diferencie maiúsculas de minusculas.

***[Funcionando em regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/UK1TnC/1)***